# Is it possible to get reference to TypedDict class used to create dictionary objects?

Tags: python

Python 3.8 introduced `TypedDict` classes that are supposed to be used for typing dict object:

```
from typing import TypedDict
class MyDict(TypedDict):
    name: str

type(MyDict(name='foo'))
# dict
```

The issue here is that the final object made from `TypedDict` is a `dict` type object and loses any sort of reference to the original creation class `MyDict`.
In other words `type(MyDict(name='foo'))` should produces `dict` objects instead `MyDict` objects.

Is it possible to patch `TypedDict` for this functionality? Alternatively maybe there's a reference in produced `dict` object to original class somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: may i ask: what would you want that for? the python interpreter is supposed to ignore the type hints (mypy or something similar take care of those).

Comment: I need data storage object which could have it's fields type checked and a have a strong name for structuring. So for example TypedDict can have it's fields typed checked but doesn't have strong name for structuring as every object comes out as `dict`, otherwise a `class Foo(dict)` can be annotated etc but type checking tools like `typeguard` doesn't support type checking annotated dicts, instead support only typedicts.

Comment: That works as expected for me `MyDict(name=1)` gives `Incompatible types (expression has type "int", TypedDict item "name" has type "str")mypy(error)`. I have mypy 0.780.

Comment: @cglacet I'm not using `mypy` in this case and that's not very relevant to my question. The major difference as far as I see between annotated dict and TypedDict is `__total__`/`total` argument that TypedDict carries, meaning you cannot replace TypeDicts with annotated dicts unless you patch in this attribute. Further on TypedDict will probably continue adding features so ideally it would be great if dict objects created of/with this typeddict would have reference to it somehow.

Comment: PEP 589 seems to contain relevant discussion for you: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/ . I haven't read it all carefully, but a quick scan gives me the impression that you are asking for something that they explicitly rejected as a goal. One quote among several: "TypedDict types can't be used in isinstance() or issubclass() checks."

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to differentiate a `TypedDict` from a `Dict` once it has been instantiated as per [PEP-589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#using-typeddict-types)

> In particular, TypedDict type objects cannot be used in `isinstance()`
> tests such as `isinstance(d, Movie)`. The reason is that there is no
> existing support for checking types of dictionary item values, since
> `isinstance()` does not work with many [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) types, including common
> ones like `List[str]`.

And looking at the [CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fbc57af851814df567fb51054cb6f6a399f814a/Lib/typing.py#L1881), we can see that `TypedDict` returns `_TypedDictMeta` which results in a [`dict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fbc57af851814df567fb51054cb6f6a399f814a/Lib/typing.py#L1872).

It boils down to the fact that it's syntactic sugar for a `dict`:

```py
'TypedDict',  # Not really a type.
```

> When called, the TypedDict type object returns an ordinary dictionary
> object at runtime:
>
> `print(type(m))  # <class 'dict'>`